# Why does springfox-swagger2 UI tell me "Unable to infer base url."

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Why does springfox-swagger2 UI tell me `Unable to infer base url.`  As far as I know, I am using a typical Swagger spring-boot configuration.

As you can see in the screenshot, the swagger-fox url backing the UI is **example.com/api** .  NOTE: I get a standard Spring `Whitelabel Error Page`  when I navigate to:  https://localhost:9600/api/v2/api-docs/  .  I suspect this is the root of the problem?  I see no errors that Spring didn't load `springfox-swagger2` and so I don't know why that isn't working.

[image]

My config looks something like this  (and I have tried all sorts of variations of this config, from searching the net for advice):

```
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.project"})
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.cloud")))
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc")))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

And

```
<!-- to generate /swagger-ui.html -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

NOTE: Interestingly, when I try version 2.6.0, I don't get the modal popup but my Swagger UI shows 0 api content.  So, i know that modal must be fairly new?

If there is not enough info here, leave me a comment.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation` and debug to find out why you are getting an error while trying to access `https://localhost:9600/api/v2/api-docs/`

Comment: check your versions of springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui. both versions should be same. I had this problem due to different versions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that the solution to my problem was to move the `@EnableSwagger2`  annotation into the main Configuration class, along with the Docket Bean.

I had created a separate class in a sub-package with the Docket Bean and I was expecting it to get scanned by Spring and load the bean.  Perhaps I failed to annotate that docket class with `@Component`,  or maybe the the problem was something else, but I got it working.

Comment: for me worked adding @ComponentScan to my SwaggerConfig class

Comment: Worked out for me adding @EnableSwagger2 annotation for my main config class. This actually happened for me in spring boot webapp.

Answer (score 54):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding SpringBootApplication with annotation - as suggested by Mark :

```
@EnableSwagger2
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed to add it. after spending so much of time. it worked like a charm !!.

Comment: I had this annotation in the `SwaggerConfig` class but the "Unable to infer base URL" error persisted.  When I moved this annotation to my `@SpringBootApplication` class, the problem went away.

Comment: Does this still work with springfox swagger 3.0.0? I have the exact same issue and this fix did not do anything.

Answer (score 29):

For me the problem was that Spring Security was not allowing access to some resources needed by swagger-ui. The solution was to allow anonymous access to the following paths:

- /swagger-ui.html
- /webjars/**
- /v2/**
- /swagger-resources/**

In my case it is fine that these resources can be accessed without authentication.

Comment: how to add this

Comment: @Gaurav : `@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {web.ignoring().mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui.html/**", "/configuration/**","/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs","/webjars/**");}`

Comment: I am not using Spring Security, same problem.

Comment: If 'not allowing anonymous' were the issue, seems like the error would different, like a permissions type of error.

Comment: Was the exact issue I had with Spring Security. Just add ```.antMatchers("/swagger-ui/*", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/v2/**", "/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()``` to the WebSecurityConfiguration.configure HttpSecurity function, amongst the rest of your code within

Answer (score 6):

Add `@EnableSwagger2` annotation in the main file of Springboot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the simplest resolution although there are other interesting ideas in this thread.

Answer (score 5):

in my case i had this line in my **WebSecurityConfig.java**:

```
.antMatchers("swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
```

and when i added this one:

```
.antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
```

my problem resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Just Extend your main class with **SpringBootServletInitalizer**.
It Will Work fine.
Take reference as bellow.

```
public class TestApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
   }
}
```

Comment: ... or mark spring-boot application with annotation: @EnableSwagger2

Answer (score 3):

This has worked for me.

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
         web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers(
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/webjars/**");
    }
```

Make sure about the root path.

Answer (score 2):

For Spring 2 use @SpringBootApplication annotation and extends your class application from SpringBootServletInitializer then override the method SpringApplicationBuilder

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TestApp.class);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using spring boot.

In my case I made mistake in package name.
in my project the base package name is

```
org.liferayasif.documents
```

so my configuration file should be inside

```
org.liferayasif.documents.config
```

config -> u can give any name.

but by mistake I put in different package name give below

```
org.liferayasif.config
```

once I put the configuration file inside proper package name in my case

```
org.liferayasif.documents.config
```

then it worked properly.

Comment: This is because Spring scans the classpath and part of what Spring scans by default  is either a 'config' folder in classpath root or a 'config' package.    This makes sense.   Whatever you do to fix this problem, just make sure Spring scanning picks up the swagger bean.    I personally wouldn't solve it this way since people who don't understand  the 'config' folder scanning will not truly understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2024 and I ran into this problem still. I tried reading all the internet but hit a lot of dead ends until I actually bumped into a solution that works. Apparently,  Spring Boot 3 needs a different library than Spring Boot 2 to be able to use Swagger 3. Let’s set it up in a new project and see how to use the most basic features.The solution was to add this dependency into the pom.xml file and boom, it worked.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You can refer to the full article [here](https://medium.com/@f.s.a.kuzman/using-swagger-3-in-spring-boot-3-c11a483ea6dc).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am deploying our **springboot(2.1.2)** with **swagger2(2.9.2)** application as war file in **tomcat8.5** and getting the same error.

Later I was able to fix just by extending this class file `AppConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer`

My complete AppConfig file

```
package org.mydomain

import java.net.URL;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "org.mydomain")
@EntityScan({"org.mydomain.entity"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"org.mydomain.repository"})
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  // We can optionally have spring boot way of starting main method
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
  }
}
```

[This is the blog I referred how to deploy springboot application into tomcat](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy)

Note: I have not configured swagger docket just used the default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add anonymous access to resources in Spring Security method: 
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)

```
.antMatchers("/api/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/v2/**", "/swagger-resources/**").anonymous()
```

And then it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

OAHH, for me it was something new. I had 2 different versions for `springfox-swagger2` and `springfox-swagger-ui`

Before:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        **<version>2.6.1</version>**
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        **<version>2.9.2</version>**
    </dependency>
```

After:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        **<version>2.9.2</version>**
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        **<version>2.9.2</version>**
    </dependency>
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but (maybe) I had a version missmatch in the pom.xml

My project version is:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.M5</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Then, It started to work when I added the following dependency:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Found at: 
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2932

Answer (score 0):

this page localhost:9000/sawgger-ui with needs other external resources like swagger-ressources /v2/api-docs ...
this resources is denyed so you mustto permit them or ignoring them

inspect your page to see it witch ressource needs to igniore or permit

Answer (score 0):

I haved same issue and spend few hours to resolved:

I use springfox **version 3.0.0**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**with springboot 2.3.10:**

```
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.10.RELEASE</version>
```

and spring security.

In my case I added paths to permitAll section  in spring security configuration

```
 .antMatchers("  "/swagger-resources/**",
                    "/swagger-ui.html",
                    "/v2/api-docs",
                    "/webjars/**" ,
                    "/swagger-ui/**")
                .permitAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

With this annotation it works for newer versions:

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher

Answer (score 0):

pay attention if you're using SPRING BOOT 3
you have to add dependency of springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this one, it's better to use swagger version below 2.7.0. I found that Springboot Application need annotaion **@EnableSwagger2** .

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -4):

Check you Java Version first, it seems to not work with Version `Java 11`, try using `Java 8` seems to be fine

Comment: have you try Java 1.2 ?