# 'unable to infer base url' Swagger-ui : Kubernetes using Traefik Ingress Controller

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, traefik-ingress

I am facing this error message when i am try to access my swagger url after it is deployed on kubernetes environment.

When i run my spring boot application on localhost then i am able to see the swagger without any error.

I am using Traefik as my ingress controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does springfox-swagger2 UI tell me "Unable to infer base url."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425048/why-does-springfox-swagger2-ui-tell-me-unable-to-infer-base-url)

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot application ,you have to add Server context path in application.yml/perporties file.

Example:

server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /

After adding context-path  you can able to see the swagger-ui
url:  localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html

Note:
Root path name as a "api", you have been configured in Ingress.yml file.

spec:
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
            serviceName: